# Powershell and Azure Resource Explorer showing different set of properties

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

I have created a private link connection to the storage account blob service, by the architecture, the private link has a private endpoint - which is linked to the interface in the virtual network and its subnet.

After the creation of the private link, the network interface which was provisioned gets the private IP address and FQDN - which is the name of the storage account and its public blob endpoint - like(myblob.blog.storage.net).

When I examine the network interface resource via Powershell, I can dig into members/properties and see the FQDN name.

**PROBLEM:** Unfortunately, I can not find any properties referencing to the private link connection on the network interface when I search via Azure Resource Explorer.

**EDIT:** Azure Resource Explorer is showing exactly the same information as to when we retrieve information via Powershell - using `Get-AzResource` command. Does this mean that we can't see all properties related to the resource via Resource Explorer as with dedicated Powershell resource commands - such as
`Get-AzNetworkInterface` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can't see all properties related to the resource via **Azure Resource Explorer**.

The reason is that **Azure Resource Explorer** and **Get-AzNetworkInterface** are using different version of api in background.

For **Azure Resource Explorer**, it's using the old api whose version is **2018-07-01**. Screenshot as below:

[image]

For **Get-AzNetworkInterface**, it's using the newest api whose version is **2019-11-01**. Screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Okay, that makes the perfect sense. Now we are coming to the solution of my core issue if I want to reference any of these **'unseen'** properties in my ARM template, for the clearness - I can use -ApiVersion parameter to override the default behavior of Get-AzResource command and retrieve proper structure with all properties included.

Comment: As an addition, people can refer to this thread/issue in order to outcome the limitation: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9451